# Why is domain adaptation and generative modelling for knowledge graphs still not applied widely in enterprise data? What are the challenges?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, applications, transfer-learning, domain-adaptation

I see that domain adaptation and transfer learning has been widely adopted in image classification and semantic segmentation analysis. But it's still lacking in providing solutions to enterprise data, for example, solving problems related to business processes?

I want to know what characteristics of the data determine the applicability or non-applicability with respect to generating models for prediction where multiple domains are involved within an enterprise information database?